# Resultant motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

if a body/a ball is travelling in a straight line with a constant velocity and I suddenly apply a finite force on it, perpendicular to its direction of motion, then it acquires a resultant motion and follows a diagonal path. I am new to physics and I am finding it quite hard to visualise how its happening. My real question is that in the very small moment when the force is applied, what is happening to the ball that makes it follow the diagonal path?

Answer (score 3):

A practical example of the deflection that you describe is that of an electron in a uniform electric field.

On entering the region in which the electric field acts the electron is subjected to a constant force and hence a constant acceleration.
The trajectory of the electron in the electric field is parabolic and when the electron leaves the region in which the electric field acts the elecron moves in a straight line.

[Here is a demonstration of the effect.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PpOAlj7sOEc)

That region over which the electric field acts can be as large or as small as you like.

[image]

An analysis of the motion [can be found here](http://www.kshitij-iitjee.com/cathode-ray-tube) with the motion in the electric field being a constant velocity perpendicular to the electric field so the displacement is proportional to the time of travel and constant acceleration along the direction of the electric field so the displacement is proportional to the time of travel squared.
This combination of the two perpendicular motions produces a parabolic path.

This is the same trajectory as that of a projectile in a uniform gravitational field.

Comment: thank you for your answer it made it quite clear:),if I got it right,what you are trying to say is that the displacement in the x direction is directly propotional to the time for which the particle traveled with a certain constant velocity and the displacement in the y axis  ie.parallel to the force vector is directly propotional to the square of time traveled in the y direction because its accelerated motion so we get a projectile motion.

Answer (score 1):

The force doesn't actually instantly change the object's direction. The object follows a curved path under the influence of the force, and then continues in a straight (diagonal) path once the force is no longer applied.

If the force is applied only for a very small instant, then this curve can be very tiny, but it always exists.

Comment: what I have read so far is that the curve might be tiny and all but any curved path is constituted by many straight paths or resultant motions,so a straight path is more fundamental than a curved one my question however was that how are these reslutant paths formed?

Comment: hi,I gave a second thought to what you said and..though curves are made of made of many straight lines of reslutant motion true but to get a resultant motion in the first place,we need to apply some kind of force and that force will produce some acceleration also it is I think impossible or atleast inconsequential to apply a force for an infintely small amount of time and when ideally a finite amount of force is applied for a finite amount of time,it will as you said result in a very small curve as also pointed out by Farcher in the other answer.So its really a very continuous process.Thanks